# How to work queue for sending verification mail on cpanel?

Tags: laravel, cron, queue, cpanel, sendmail

Successfully enable mail verification using redis in locally in my laravel project. But when this project upload in cpanel verification mail not send and didn't give any error.

I am using both shared and dedicated hosting.

I used smtp gmail in .env.

how to enable or work queue in cpanel.

Answer (score 0):

On you AppServiceProvider.php

```
use Artisan;
```

and past this inside boot method

```
Artisan::call("queue:listen");
```

Comment: Sorry, this time site not run